# How to determine the elevation of the average citizen of a given region?

Tags: data-request, population

In a recent course on steam systems for heating and humidification in buildings, we were instructed to use the atmospheric pressure at sea level as a starting point for calculations related to pressure, temperature, and enthalpy of steam at various points in a given system.

In other areas of building design we use averaged values from censuses and recorded weather data, so why not do the same for elevation?

**Is there a data source which contains (or which could be used to obtain) the average elevation of a citizen of a given region, such as nation, state/province, or county?**

Obviously if I know the city of a proposed or existing building I can easily look up the elevation there, but when analyzing proposed buildings, or averages of buildings in a given region, mean elevation won't do -- the population-weighted mean would be more appropriate.

Comment: The seemingly-obvious method would be to use the smallest land for which you have population and elevation information (eg, a Census blockgroup) and add the population times elevation and then divide by population, no?